# Invalid image example on Established User help page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, help-center, privileges-page

On the StackOverflow page about [Established User privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), it shows 2 pictures of usercards, one of which are supposed to expand.

[image: find a difference!]

Um... there's not really a (visible) difference is there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depicts the real difference between the two styles. The avatar of the one on the left has a drop shadow (hence is expandable), and that of the one on the right does not (and so is not expandable).

[image]

Notice the little gray gradient/fuzziness. It's subtle!

Comment: @scriptHero I don't think so. Anything less subtle will become too noisy. I don't want to start seeing flashing colors all around.